# SAML 2.0 XMLSignatureClass init() failure

Tags: java, xml, saml-2.0, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to implement a SAML 2.0 connection.  I've done a lot of searching and the closest I've found to sample code using ColdFusion is here:

http://dragonsaber.blogspot.com/2009/09/coldfusion-saml-part-1.html

http://dragonsaber.blogspot.com/2010/01/coldfusion-saml-part-2.html

http://dragonsaber.blogspot.com/2010/04/coldfusion-saml-part-3.html

http://philduba.com/default/assets/File/BeyondEncryp-cfobjective-2013.pdf

Below is a snippet of my implementation of the code.  My target ColdFusion platform is version 10.

```
<cfscript>
    ssouser = {
        'email': 'user@domain.com',
        'name': 'User',
        'uuid': CreateUUID()
    };
    nowDateTime = DateFormat(DateConvert('local2utc', Now()), 'YYYY-MM-DDT') & TimeFormat(DateConvert('local2utc', Now()), 'HH:mm:SS.LZ');
    nowDateTimePlus1 = DateFormat(DateConvert('local2utc', Now()), 'YYYY-MM-DDT') & TimeFormat(DateConvert('local2utc', DateAdd('n', 1, Now())), 'HH:mm:SS.LZ');
    IDPDomain = "idp.domain.com";
    SPService = "sp.domain.com";
    SPDomain = "domain.com";
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
    <cfxml variable="samlAssertionXML">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <samlp:Response Destination="#SPService#" ID="#ssouser.uuid#" IssueInstant="#nowDateTime#" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">#IDPDomain#</saml:Issuer>
        <samlp:Status>
            <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
        </samlp:Status>
        <saml:Assertion ID="#ssouser.uuid#" IssueInstant="#nowDateTime#" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
            <saml:Issuer>#IDPDomain#</saml:Issuer>
            <saml:Subject>
                <saml:NameID>#ssouser.email#</saml:NameID>
                <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:2.0:cm:bearer">
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="#ssouser.uuid#" NotOnOrAfter="#nowDateTimePlus1#" Recipient="#SPService#"/>
                </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
            <saml:Conditions NotBefore="#nowDateTime#" NotOnOrAfter="#nowDateTimePlus1#">
                <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                    <saml:Audience>#SPDomain#</saml:Audience>
                </saml:AudienceRestriction>
            </saml:Conditions>
            <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="#nowDateTime#">
                <saml:AuthnContext>
                    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
                </saml:AuthnContext>
            </saml:AuthnStatement>
            <saml:AttributeStatement>
                <saml:Attribute Name="screenName">
                    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">#ssouser.name#</saml:AttributeValue>
                </saml:Attribute>
            </saml:AttributeStatement>
        </saml:Assertion>
    </samlp:Response>
    </cfxml>
</cfoutput>

<cfscript>
    // 1) Injest the XML
    samlAssertionElement = samlAssertionXML.getDocumentElement();
    samlAssertionDocument = samlAssertionElement.GetOwnerDocument();
    samlAssertion = samlAssertionDocument.getFirstChild();

//writedump(samlAssertionDocument); // show variable type of samlAssertionDocument
//abort;

    // 2) Create Java Objects
    SignatureSpecNS = CreateObject("Java", "org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants").SignatureSpecNS;
    SecInit = CreateObject("Java", "org.apache.xml.security.Init").Init().init();
    XMLSignatureClass = CreateObject("Java", "org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature"); // Access XML Signature CLASS
    CanonicalizerClass = CreateObject("Java", "org.apache.xml.security.c14n.Canonicalizer"); // Access Canonicalizer CLASS

    // 3) Signature
    sigType = XMLSignatureClass.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1; // Define signature algorithm
    canonType = CanonicalizerClass.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS; // Define canonicalizer algorithm
    // init fails on the next line.
    signature = XMLSignatureClass.init(samlAssertionDocument, javacast("string",""), sigType, canonType); // Create signature and apply algorithms
</cfscript>
```

Everything appears to work until it gets to the last line of code where it tries to create the signature object.  Here is the failure message from ColdFusion:

```
Unable to find a constructor for class org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature that accepts parameters of type ( org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String ).
```

I looked through the source code for XMLSignature.java and the closest matching constructor is:

```
public XMLSignature(
    Document doc, 
    String baseURI, 
    String signatureMethodURI,
    String canonicalizationMethodURI
) throws XMLSecurityException {
    this(doc, baseURI, signatureMethodURI, 0, canonicalizationMethodURI);
}
```

Continuing to look at XMLSignature.java, the first argument is Document and it looks like it should be an "org.w3c.dom.Document".

I suspect that the problem is that the type of the first argument (The variable "samlAssertionDocument") is of type "org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl" and Java isn't able to make the cast to "org.w3c.dom.Document".

I've tried javacast() and it seems to only works with the standard types.

Is there a way to easily convert this variable to the type that the constructor is expecting?  If there is a different problem, please let me know.

I've seen similar SAML 2.0 examples published on two different blogs but they were from 2009/2010 and using ColdFusion MX/8.

I'm using the Apache Santuario project (Apache XML Security for Java 1.5.8).  Version 1.5.8 includes JAR files that were easy to use.  I set up a folder on the test site and used the "this.javaSettings" feature of Application.cfc to connect to them.

I would use the newer 2.0.5 version but it seems to only come in source format.  That is, I'd have to figure out how to create the JAR files.

Comment: I do not have answer, but a few observations 1) Are you looking at the source code for the version of `XMLSignature` that you are using? Dump the instance constructors, what do you see? 2) `org.w3c.dom.Document` is an interface.  According to an API found online org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl implements that interface. So that may not be the problem  3) Are you using javacast on all three of the String arguments?

Comment: 1) Yes, I believe so, the source & JARs are in the same ZIP file.  I have dumped the instance; writedump(XMLSignatureClass) but it doesn't display the constructors.  2) It might not be the problem. 3) I have added javacast to the other string arguments but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: For constructors you need to use a [little reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctor.html) ie `theObject.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors()`.  Though it is not indicated by that specific error, there is always the possibility of class loader conflicts when dynamic class loaders are involved. Especially as CF has added a lot of libraries since those articles were written.

Comment: OK, I'm going to take some time to learn about reflection.  Would you recommend moving the JARs into the {cfusionhome}\cfusion\lib folder and restarting CF?  I noticed that some of the JARs are there without version numbers; example: serializer.jar vs. serializer-2.7.2.jar.  However, the main JAR used for this code is xmlsec-1.5.8.jar and it doesn't appear to be in the CF libs folder.

Comment: I normally avoid that because the presence of those jars in \lib means they are being used for other CF functionality. Without thorough testing, there is always a possibility changing the jar version could break something. That said, it would not hurt to try it on a DEV server.  Just be sure to back up the original jars first. Then if it does not work, you just remove the new jars - restore the old ones - and you are back to the original state.

Comment: *some of the JARs are there without version* Use 7zip to open the jars (do not extract them) and check meta-inf\manifest file. It usually contains a version number.

Comment: @Leigh I did open the JARs with WinRAR and did look at them.  Some of them were the same, others were 0.0.1 version off.